# How to update `foundation-icons-sass-rails` 2 to 3 in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I used `foundation-icons-sass-rails` version 2 in rails 4.

I want to update foundation icon set version 2 to 3, so I write in Gemfile like this.

```
gem "foundation-icons-sass-rails", "~> 3.0.0"
```

After that I run `bundle install` and affirmed the gem is updated to version `3.0.0`.
And restart rails server. But still I can't use icons of version 3.

I can only use icon in version 2 way like this.

If I write like `<i class=fi-refresh>`, no icons appears.

What should do to use foundation icons set in rails 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a temporary fix, add this to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'foundation-icons-sass-rails', github: 'jasontorres/foundation-icons-sass-rails'
```

Then run:

```
bundle

rake assets:clean

rake assets:precompile
```

Don't forget to remove the github part when a new version of the gem is released.